# Add Doppler RADAR as a Layer in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, web-service

I am hoping for an answer here even though it's a long shot. My goal is to add a raster service into ArcMap that shows the Doppler RADAR information that is shown at the Weather Office website.

I am hoping that this data can be dynamic, so that I can do analysis of it and so that it refreshes every ten minutes or so.

I work for a Government organization, so there should be no private sector issues.

Over the last month I've sent out quite a few emails to different possible data sources. Each one has not really had an idea about what I am inquiring about.

Here is an image of what I am looking for. If you want to check out the website [click here](http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/radar/index_e.html?id=ONT).
[image: Doplar RADAR]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are rest endpoints and wms services you can use to access the data, but I am confused about how you will do analysis. If you are processing and the ten minutes is up which image are you going to process?
What type of analysis are you referring to?

[arcgisonline](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=radar%20canada&t=content)
[Noaa US Radar](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=34aa493f4f504bd488d0f6ca91e8bf1f)
If you select the arrow next to open you get the option to open in arcmap desktop.  then an F5 will refresh "when" there is a new "current" image.

[image: radar]

Comment: I am hoping to use the raster image (it definitly seems like a raster pained on a base map), to grab information from it based on points. Example: I want to use the raster to find out how much rain fell on an xy point based on the cm/hour of the raster cell closest. Since the map updates every hour (on the website) it would be an analysis run every hour. I think that defines a good example of sort of what I plan on doing with this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked out a few of the services and was able to find one that looks to [work](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7625d5440fbb43bc9767f4613a1a1b3a). Now I am not sure whether this data updates or not. At the present it says that I should be getting around 10 cm of snow per hour. And well, it's a beauty day, so that's wrong. But it can be queried, analyzed and identified. Now to check whether it updates and if it's source is accurate and verified.

Answer (score 1):

So this really may not answer your question - but it's more information. I have downloaded doppler data from http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/nexradinv/chooseday.jsp?id=kohx and converted it to an arc readable format (using their java toolkit). It wasn't a live service but I didn't need it live - I wanted historical. I believe the NWS runs a service that is importable into arc - but your example points to canadia and I have no idea.

I'll be the worst answering person ever - let me look for the service that arc can read from NOAA/NWS

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTICE:** *Environment Canada forecasts and analysis layers. Theses web services are available for demo/prototype/pilot purposes only.
>   This is not an operational server.*

Regardless, it looks like these services are updated every 20 mins and the following WMS url can also be used for the WFS url so that you can use the data directly (mostly lines that you need to *grid* yourself).

Environment Canada has a WMS at **http://wms.weatheroffice.gc.ca/geomet/** and the *Get Capabilities* document is here for more info: *http://wms.weatheroffice.gc.ca/geomet/?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities*

Supposedly available as KML: *http://wms.weatheroffice.gc.ca/geomet/?SERVICE=KML&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetKML*

[image: Environment Canada WMS showing precipitation in mm.]

[image: Environment Canada WMS showing Radar Composite Reflectivity @ 2KM resolution.]

**Data Verification:**
[image: Environment Canada Identify Results on Temperature layer @ 51.0978 F]
Hotspot to the left of chart shows Lat/Lon of 34.0734,-90.0925 and 51.0978degF.

[image: Image from AccuWeather.com]
Temperature from AccuWeather.com shows same temperature =)